# Why do i get this error when trying to check if in Corona sdk?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

```
if myGameSettings.HighScore > highScore.text then
end
```

I am trying to check if this conditions is true but i get this error saying
attempt to compare string with number

I have tried to use it like this too

```
if tonumber(myGameSettings.HighScore) > tonumber(highScore.text) then
end
```

Comment: Then what did you get after change, what's wrong?

Comment: Can you show or print the contents of `myGameSettings.HighScore` and  `highScore.text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be `highScore.text` you are using is a string value.